# I am having issues with subdivision surface

Tags: modeling

20 year Max user here learning Blender. I am trying to use the subdivision surface modifier to make my low poly mesh into a high poly mesh so I can bake a normal map. I have inset all the faces on this dumpster mesh and it looks fine in the viewport, but when I apply the subserf modifier, the mesh distorts horribly and nothing seems to make it better. What am I doing wrong? Why am I not seeing quads--it's giving me these wierd looking distortions.I'm lost! Thanks guys[image]

Comment: Are you simply trying to subdivide the faces, without smoothing the geometry? Switch the modifier to the "Simple" mode and untick "Optimal Display" below to see the added subdivisions. Is that what you're looking for? If not, try to give more detail or an example of what you would expect to see.

Comment: Hi--I want the outside edges (where I have inset the faces) to be slightly rounded, the flat surfaces should stay flat

Answer (score 3):

Inset faces is not going to help a lot with the subdivision modifier
You need to bevel the edges, add support edges or use Edge Crease;
Take a look a this image

From Left to Right

Edge Crease, Support edges, Bevel, Inset faces

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I don't get--support loops are really no different than inset faces so why is the end result different?

Comment: Take a look at the image, support edges are loop cuts, and the inset are cuts that goes from corner to corner

Comment: @bobcooksey Left = Inset - Right = Support loops (or bevel with shape = 1 and 2 segments) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipgrk.png

Comment: @bobcooksey Inset faces are very different from bevelled faces. [Catmull-Clark Subdiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) bases its interpolation per-face, and per-edge. The inset faces span entire edges. The bevelled edges introduce new faces at the corners. splitting up the interpolation. It's a good rule of thumb,  to avoid 5 or 6 poles at points of high curvature.. actually that's another way of looking at the same problem. It's  quite instructive to work through a subdiv or two by hand, with pencil and paper. Once done, never forgotten. :)